# How to delete an item in Firebase Database based on specific time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am creating an Android app in Java that allows the user to create swap requests which I want t to delete from the real-time database when its swapShiftdate comes to its date. so I can release the database constantly.
let's say the user created his swap on Monday and swap date is Thursday in real life. the swap should be deleted from the database when Thursday comes so it does not appear to users anymore. I want a way that helps me delete them based on the date they have chosen as its shown in the screen-shot.

[image]

Comment: Are you going to check if a swap should be deleted only once a day or several times a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check every day if there are `swaps` to delete, based on the `swapperShiftDay` field value, and if it is the case, delete them, you could write an HTTPS Cloud Function as follows and call it every day via an online cron job like https://cron-job.org/en/

The HTTPS Cloud Function would look like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteSwaps = functions
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {

      const dbRef = admin.database().ref('swaps/shift_swaps').orderByChild("swapperShiftDay").equalTo(getTodayDateString());
      dbRef.once('value')
              .then(snapshot => {
                  var updates = {};
                  snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                      key = childSnapshot.key;
                      updates['swaps/shift_swaps/' + key] = null;
                  });
                  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
              })
              .then(() => {
                  res.send({ msg: 'Success' });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  res.status(500).send({Error: err});
              });
  });

function getTodayDateString() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";

  return weekday[d.getDay()];
}
```

Comment: @Ahmed Rabee Hello, did you have time to evaluate/try the proposed solution in my answer?

Comment: Hi Renaud, I am really thankful for your help. I know my response is too late and I am sorry for that but I have had my issues and I apologize for that. From a weak from now,

Comment: I have decided to learn JavaScript to understand your code and I have just started ECMA 6 and now I am able to understand your code now and I have deployed it successfully to my functions, and have created cron schedule for it with the function link. my only problem is that I have tried to use the URL in my browser to check if the function work or not and It print this error (ReferenceError: firebase is not definedfailed).

Comment: I am not gonna lie to you I have just learned the language syntax and I don't know why it shows this error and now searching for a way to solve it. also, I didn't check the answer as I wanted to check it with all the steps I have done after it works with me. Thx again for your assist I am really glad for it.

Comment: Hello. Normally with the code I provided it should work without problem. Maybe a problem of deployment? Maybe you could follow this Get Started post: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0

Comment: there were tow small bugs while deploying the first is (error Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return) which I solved by adding a return to the second then. and changed ( res.status(500).send('Error': err);) to ( res.status(500).send({'Error': err});). The function is deployed successfully and I have created a cron job for it calls it every day at 0:00
but when I try to use the URL in the browser to check if the function works it catch the error ({"Error":{}})

Comment: I have got it now it's because I am using the free service from Firebase. the log message was (Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions). I guess it will work after starting my paid server with them when I deploy the app.